# Помогите написать цикл для JSON ответа

Tags: python, for, while

Есть массив JSON, вот выражение для печати одной строки массива:

```
print(r_write_iops['entries'][0]['content']['values']['spb']['dae_1_0_disk_0']) выводит значение
```

Требуется перебрать в цикле dae_1_0_disk_X, так как дисков много. Как лучше сделать? Называние диском может быть

```
                        "dpe_disk_5": 2323
                        "dpe_disk_4": 2323
                        "dpe_disk_7": 2323
                        "dae_1_0_disk_7": 2323
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно вас понял, то так:

```
for n in range(0, x):
    diskid = 'dae_1_0_disk_' + n
    print(r_write_iops['entries'][0]['content']['values']['spb'][diskid])
```

Может быть, вам лучше подойдёт такой вариант:

```
disks = ['dae_1', 'dpe_2', 'abc_3']
for diskid in disks:
    print(r_write_iops['entries'][0]['content']['values']['spb'][diskid])
```

Или так:

```
disks = ['dae_1_0_disk_', 'dpe_disk_']
digits = range(0, 9)
for disk in disks:
    for n in digits:
        print(r_write_iops['entries'][0]['content']['values']['spb'][disk + n])
```

Четвертый вариант

```
disks = ['dae_1_0_disk_', 'dpe_disk_']
digits = range(0, 9)
for disk in disks:
    for n in digits:
        disk_id = disk + str(n)
        disk_value = r_write_iops['entries'][0]['content']['values']['spb'][disk_id]
        print(disk_id + ' : ' + disk_value)
```

Comment: Не совсем, диски еще имеют названия и другие, , могут быть просто dae_2 , dpe_4

Comment: Тогда конкретизируйте, какие они могут быть. Из оригинального вопроса я понял, что меняется циыра в конце. В вопрос внесите изменение.

Comment: Добавил в исходное, какие могут быть

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил третий вариант.

Comment: почти, но не выводит название дисков в print,только значение, а если мне надо и значение выводить и названия этих дисков

Comment: Следующей строкой после этого `print` с таким же отступом нужно сделать еще один `print`, который выводит нужное вам значение. Вы знаете, что имеется в виду под "значением диска", это ваша бизнес-логика, которую знаете, может быть, только вы.

Comment: "dpe_disk_5": 2323
                        "dpe_disk_4": 2323
                        "dpe_disk_7": 2323
                        "dae_1_0_disk_7": 2323  мне надо вот так, а выводит вот так 2323, 2323 просто значение с каждой строки, и причем мне надо к каждому элементу потом иметь доступ будь то dpe_disk_7 или его знаечение

Comment: Дополнил. Смотрите.

Comment: Ошибка :     disk_id = disk + n
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: забыл str(). Исправил

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects тоже самое

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

```py
for k, v in r_write_iops['entries'][0]['content']['values']['spb'].items():
    if 'disk' in k:
        print('Disk - %s, Value - %s' % (k, v))
```

Comment: А как мне встроить это в конструкцию?  EMC2_AVRG.labels('S', 'HDD', 'Storage', 'Тут значение Disk %s', 'bandwidth').set(%s тут значение Value)